Unlock all handwritten notes in a pdf document
I wrote a word document and got it back from a reviewer as an annotated pdf file with handwritten notes (I guess they were made on a tablet or sth.) To finalize my document, I would like to include these remarks in my word file. For that I want to delete single notes from the pdf whenever I included the comment in my final document, so I can track where I am in my process.
All of these notes are locked so I cannot simply delete them by pressing DEL. I can delete them only after I open the single notes properties and uncheck a mark at locked.
Since there are a lot of notes, this means a lot of unnecessary steps for me. Is there a way to unlock all of the comments/notes at once?

Try this tool (supposedly free).

I already did, but it does not seem to work for handwritten notes unfortunately.
